# Thunderbird Profile on LUKS Encrypted flash drive not working

Tags: encryption, usb-drive, thunderbird, luks

I want to store my Thunderbird profile on an encrypted USB flash drive and run it from there because I often switch between two computers with identical setups: Ubuntu 14.04 with the same user accounts.

I used the "Disk" utility in Ubuntu 14.04 to format and create a LUKS partition on my USB flash drive. I copied my Thunderbird profile on the USB key.

```
******** parted -l ********************

Model: ATA WDC WD1001FALS-0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  106MB   105MB   primary   ntfs            boot
 2      106MB   210GB   210GB   primary   ntfs
 3      210GB   1000GB  790GB   extended
 6      210GB   992GB   782GB   logical   ext4
 5      992GB   1000GB  8579MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)


Model: SanDisk Cruzer Glide (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdf: 16.0GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      16.4kB  16.0GB  16.0GB  primary               boot


Model: Linux device-mapper (crypt) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/luks-f28c6ec0-ad18-4346-a6ed-5fd0c527a3ad: 16.0GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  16.0GB  16.0GB  ext4
*********************************************
```

I edited the profiles.ini in the .thunderbird folder to point to the profile on the usb key.

```
***********/.thunderbird/profile.ini **********
[General]
StartWithLastProfile=1

[Profile0]
Name=default
IsRelative=0
Path=/media/slimms/UUI/o86uypvt.default
**********************
```

Now when I run Thunderbird, I get the welcome screen asking me to create a new account.

The thing is, before I encrypted this USB key, everything was working with this path to the same unencrypted USB key.

How to make this work?